# mod_rewrite from http port XXXX to https port XXXY

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I can't get mod_rewrite work with the following Rules.

```
RewriteCond "%{SERVER_NAME}" "home.myhome.net"
RewriteCond "%{SERVER_PORT}" "^4388$"
RewriteRule (.*) https://home.myhome.net:4389%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L]
```

This Rule is set on my http virtual host section. Problem is, that redirect only works the first time. The second time when I enter a differnt URL on http port 4388 I get redirected to **https**://home.myhome.net:438**8**/...

for example:

- first I enter http://home.myhome.net:4388/pageA I get redirected to https://home.myhome.net:4389/pageA
- next time I enter http://home.myhome.net:4388/pageB and get redirected to http**s**://home.myhome.net:438**8**/pageB

Any Idea how to fix that?

My OS details:

```
root@host:~# dpkg -l|grep apache
ii  apache2                                     2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5                            amd64        Apache HTTP Server
ii  apache2-bin                                 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5                            amd64        Apache HTTP Server (modules and other binary files)
ii  apache2-data                                2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5                            all          Apache HTTP Server (common files)
ii  apache2-utils                               2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5                            amd64        Apache HTTP Server (utility programs for web servers)
ii  python-certbot-apache                       0.17.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1             all          Apache plugin for Certbot
root@host:~# lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
```

That's my Virtual Host Config, it is something different because I made some more tests, but same behavior. I also dropped for testing all other rewrite rules, with same result (and how I told in comments, for every test I flush my browser cache).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@myhome.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond "%{SERVER_NAME}" "home.myhome.net"
        RewriteCond "%{SERVER_PORT}" "^4388$"
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}:4389%{REQUEST_URI} [noescape,qsappend,redirect=301,last]
    </IfModule>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Oh, and I forgot to say, that this server is behind a NAT Gateway, which does a port forwarding from external port 4388 to internal host port 80 and also external port 4389 to internal port 443. Thats why I need to check for the port and hostname to match only external traffic.

**EDIT**: Okay, I have found something, but also don't have a solution:
I compared the first and following browser request/response with the browser developer tools->network tab:

The first request give me the "*301 Moved Permanently*", but the following request gives me a "*307 Internal Redirect*".

So this seems a Server problem. Question is only, if it is a Bug in mod_rewrite or is it my fault, because the Rule is not okay.

**EDIT**: I tested now also with the current apache version 2.4.27-5.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 from [Ondřej Surý's Apache PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2)

Regards,
Thomas

Comment: The directive you have posted shouldn't work at all. You are missing a space before the RewriteRule flags. However, since you are in a virtual host context, is there any need to check the SERVER_NAME and PORT? (Presumably UseCanonicalName is Off?) In which case this could be simplified with a mod_alias Redirect. However, anything that works on the first try, but not the second smells of a caching issue.

Comment: What happens if you request `/pageB` "first"? The directive you have posted is not the cause of this (although in its current state it is wrong and will not do anything - I assume that must be a typo, since you've not commented/corrected this?). It's either a caching issue (as mentioned), or "something else" is going on. Please post the relevant directives/virtual host containers from your server config.

Comment: @MrWhite: its is the same behavior when I access pageB first. And sorry, the missing space was my copy & paste fault in my setup it is the with the space. I have also at least put this rewrite rule on top of any other rule - but without a change.

Comment: And the check for host name is not really needed, but nice to have, that no everybody who access the website with the ip (not hostname) get the redirect to the https website and so know the dyn-hostname.

Comment: oh and I have flushed my cache between all my tests. also tested with a different browser (so I tested with chrome and ie11).

Comment: I added my vhost-config.

Comment: I tested now also with firefox, same problem.. after the first access, every access after that is getting https on the wrong port.

Comment: These directives are in a VirtualHost container for port 80, yet you are checking for port 4388 using mod_rewrite - I don't see how this can work at all? `SERVER_PORT` is the _internal_ port on your application server ie. 80 (which is the only port it can be if this VirtualHost matches), not the _external_ port that your "NAT Gateway" sees. (?) Where are you defining the `ServerName`? Do you also define a port? (If you specifically want to check the Host used in the request, it is safer to use `HTTP_HOST` instead.)

Comment: the servername is defined, because of random ips, thats why i need a dyn-host. And I think, server port it the port, which I client report that the connect come frome (with the GET request). Why else should the initial connect work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66223/discussion-between-thomas-and-mrwhite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after long search I finally found the reason. I had set the HTTP Strict-Transport-Security (HSTS) on my https website, thats why the browser don't start again to open a http website on that url and force https protocol.

The given examples are all working.